# MLE estimator for $f(y|p)=p^y(1-p)^{1-y}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Consider the density function $f(y|p)=p^y(1-p)^{1-y}$ where $y\in \{0,1\}$. Given a random sample $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$, I want to find the maximum likelihood estimator for $p$. The likelihood is given by
$$
L(y|p)=(p^y(1-p)^{1-y})^n
$$
Usually to find the maximum likelihood I would set the derivative equal to zero, however, the derivative of $L(y|p)$ evaluated at zero is indeterminate. So how do I find it when I cannot use the derivative?

**Edit**: as has been pointed out, the above is not the correct likelihood. The correct should be
$$
\begin{equation}
L(y \mid p)=\prod_{i=1}^n p^{y_i}(1-p)^{1-y_i}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: That's not the correct likelihood function. Also, this question has been asked many times already.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. You write $y\in\{0,1\}$. If you mean that literally, then $f$ is a probability mass function, not a distribution function. Also, the displayed equation shows the likelihood of the same result $y$ occurring $n$ times, which is not what you need.

Comment: @joriki, I meant density function. I have corrected it

Comment: @Manó: That doesn't solve the problem. A density function is still a continuous function. If you really mean $y\in\{0,1\}$, then $f$ is not a continuous function.

Comment: @joriki: in the problem statement it says that $Y_1, Y_2, ...,Y_2$ is a sample on $Y\sim b(1,p)$ and therefore that $f_Y(y|p)=p^y(1-p)^{1-y}$ with $y\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: That's fine – but then $f$ isn't a density function but a probability mass function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the log of $L$ first, and then use the first order condition to identify the best value for $p$. The reason this will work is that the log is a strictly increasing function, so the maximizer of L will be the same as the maximizer of log L.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log L &= \sum_{i=1}^n \log(p^{y_i}(1-p)^{1-y_i}) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\log p + (1-y_i) \log (1-p) 
\end{aligned}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dp}\log L &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i}{p} - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1-y_i}{1-p} \\
&= \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \frac{1}{1-p}\left(n-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$

If we let $\bar y = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$, then just a little bit of algebra shows that $\frac{d}{dp}\log L = 0$ iff $p = \bar y$.